# Appending dom object with attached events to new popup window causes events not to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

In my web application I show the user an overview of information in a system in different containers. Some of these containers can be nice to "pop out" into a separate window to allow the user to drag the window to a separate screen to get a better overview of the information(maps, schduler etc).

My problem occurs when trying to use the newly appended container in the newly created window. The html is there but the events are not working.

I have simplified my problem here: http://frankyboy.se/test/slider/test.html

What the page does is it imports jquery and jquery ui.
It initializes the jquery ui slider widget.
It then creates a new window when pressing a button, waits a second, then appends the slider to the new window.

The slider works in the original window but stops working in the new window.

Can anyone explain why and maybe how to fix this ?

**UPDATE**:

Ok it seems like at least the slider widget has problems running in a separate window. Maybe it is up to the plugin to support being able to be moved or initialized in a child window. My latest example shows two buttons, one opening up a new window and creating a slider and the other opening up a new window and creating a button. You can clearly see that the slider is dependent on the parent window since the slider will only move when you move the mouse in the parent window. http://frankyboy.se/test/slider/parent.html

To test the slider, click the first button, the slider appears in the child window. Click the slider, nothing will happen, move the mouse to the same position in the parent window and pretend there is an invisible slider there in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

In your new window opened, you only append the container to the new document, but you have to call `$("#test").slider();` again to let the slider to work.

[updated working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rqN5w/)

Comment: Why should I have to do that ?
Appending it to another div doesn't require reinitialization.
Here is another example showing a button as well.
The button keeps its events.
http://frankyboy.se/test/slider/test2.html

Comment: @ViktorEriksson you are adding the slider in after 1 second the page loads, which the slider won't get initialized. `$("#test").slider();` is called before you append the container.

Comment: Alan is right because if you execute $("#test").slider(); in the console (Chrome Javascript console) after the page is loaded it works... but I could not get the right code to put in the html to make it work. Out of curiosity, can you please post it Alan?

Comment: @flopo updated with a working example, notice on line 8, just initialize the slider after we insert the element in the new document.

Comment: Does not work for me: you are opening a page from another different page. Try create a simple html and work on it (not in a fiddle). If you don't have a webserver, just start Chrome allowing local access and work in a local html file. I'm curious with this problem.

Comment: First of all I cannot see anything being appended in Alan Wu's example. $("#container").appendTo is executed but there are no #container. Second of all, I know I can initialize everything again but that is not something I want. In this example I'm throwing the slider between two divs and it works without reinitialization http://jsfiddle.net/KfwUQ/. Maybe some internal works of the slider and other plugins. Maybe the event is somehow connected to the window object it was created in.